# Rebase a branch backwards to master branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-rebase

I have a feature branch B that is made off of a feature branch A. I want to rebase branch B back onto master without branch A's commits.

My repository looks like this:

```
c1---c2---c3  master
            \
             c4---c5---c6  A
                        \
                        c7---c8---c9  B
```

What I want is this:

```
             c7---c8---c9 B
            /
c1---c2---c3  master
            \
             c4---c5---c6  A
```

I tried doing a rebase from branch B onto master. That did not do anything and kept branch B on branch A.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible to trace back from `B` to `master`, so as far as Git is concerned branch `B` is already "on" `master`. In other words, `B` "contains" `master`.

Try being explicit about the branch to be rebased and and the upstream:

```
git rebase --onto master A B
```

Comment: `rebase` changes the hash of my brain :-s Every time I think I've finally got the gist of it, I stumble upon another mode which confuses me. I guess I just got a bit more [reading](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---ontoltnewbasegt) to do now...

Answer (score 5):

A 3 lines cherry-pick solution, less concise than Chris' excellent answer but maybe clearer to some, could go like this :

```
git branch backup-B B
git checkout -B B master
git cherry-pick A..backup-B
```

---

**Explanation of the steps :**

**1) make a backup** (also serving as reference for later cherry-pick)

```
git branch backup-B B
```

---

```
c1---c2---c3  <<< master
            \
             c4---c5---c6  <<< A
                        \
                        c7---c8---c9  <<< backup-B, B <<< HEAD
```

**2) point B at master** (and check it out in the same time)

```
git checkout -B B master
```

---

```
c1---c2---c3  <<< master, B <<< HEAD
            \
             c4---c5---c6  <<< A
                        \
                        c7---c8---c9  <<< backup-B
```

**3) "copy" the missing commits** (NOT reachable from A but reachable from "old" B, here `c7`, `c8`, `c9`)

```
git cherry-pick A..backup-B
```

---

```
             c7'---c8'---c9'  <<< B <<< HEAD
            /
c1---c2---c3  <<< master
            \
             c4---c5---c6  <<< A
                        \
                        c7---c8---c9  <<< backup-B
```

*(of course at this point, although not necessary, you could just drop the backup with `git branch -D backup-B` to obtain the exact result you asked for. However, such a lifejacket is a light burden on the gititanic ;-)*

Answer (score 4):

Along with the offered solution, here's a third one.

You can run an interactive rebase. When checked out on `B`, run `git rebase --interactive master`. Your `$EDITOR` will be opened with the following:

```
pick c4 Message of c4
pick c5 Message of c5
pick c6 Message of c6
pick c7 Message of c7
pick c8 Message of c8
pick c9 Message of c9
```

Here you just then need to remove the commits belonging to `A`, so you need to make the file look like:

```
pick c7 Message of c7
pick c8 Message of c8
pick c9 Message of c9
```

Then, save and quit, and *voila*.